# Деление в ассемблере?

Tags: ассемблер

Как разделить число 14A162 на число 1234?

Answer (score 5):

Кажется так:

```
mov eax, 14A162h
mov ebx, 1234h
div ebx
```

в eax будет частное, в edx - остаток

Comment: DIV r/m

Comment: fail :)
ну значит mov ebx, 1234h ; div ebx

Answer (score 0):

```
ars3    movlw   0x09
    movwf   sec
    movlw   0x00
    movwf   stp

ars4   `movlw   0x03
    subwf   sec,f
    movlw   0x01
    addwf   stp,f
    btfsc   stat,z
    goto    rst1
    btfss   stat,z
    goto    ars4
```